# awesome-wm: how do I change the tiling layout to prefer 3x2 (cols x rows) instead of 2x3?

Tags: awesome-wm

How can I change awesome to prefer more narrow windows over wide windows. I have a fancy 4k monitor with plenty of space, but for example when I have 6 windows open, all the layours prefer showing me a 2x3 layout instead of 3x2.

```
awful.tag.incncol( 1, nil, true)
```

This does nothing for me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does it have to be a tiling layout? If you use the `fair.horizontal` layout, you get exactly the distribution you want to achieve. Its icon also looks just like what you want to get, I think.

Comment: Oki I'll give it a go, thanks!